Craft CMS 2 - Not Loading elements in Admin - SSL Offloading Mode
We're working on a website on a virtual server with CraftCMS 2.6.2984
The website has been having a very slow time-to-first-byte, at around 10 sec, although, when using viewing the developer tools (with dev mode on), the queries on the home page timed at 0.7 sec.  Viewing in the network tab showed that the response time for the document was averaging at 10 sec.  I might add that the slow response time mentioned above is the very slowest, and that the behavior is somewhat inconsistent, with response times varying from .9 sec to the aforementioned 10 sec.
We had been in SSL passthrough mode on our host's load balancer, but then we changed to SSL offload and (perhaps coincidentally?) gained speed in page load.  However, the tradeoff is that none of the elements are loading in the Admin section.
Would adding/changing https settings in the config file be the answer here?
Thanks for your help

I'd be looking at the server spec/setup, and updating Craft before doing anything else. Very old server + very old CMS will generally give you very poor results…
